# How to prevent duplicate entry in sqlite

Tags: android

i need to prevent duplicates entry in sqlite  i made this code but it not working.

```
String brandName=BrandName.getText().toString().trim();
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Brand_Table WHERE Name="+brandName, null);
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                showMessage("Error", "Record exist");
            }
            else
            {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("Name", brandName);
                db.insert("Brand_Table", null, values);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Brand  Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BrandName.setText("");

            }
```

Error Logs

```
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: abc (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Brand_Table WHERE Name=abc
```

my database look likes

```
id   Name
1    abc
2    pqr
```

id is auto incremented  i am passing value abc from edittext and data is present in database but it gives above error and stop application

Comment: if `Name` is string, you need to use quotes

Comment: share the code of create table.

Comment: You could do the same thing with the `UNIQUE` constraint (which is much safer to use than custom code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Brand_Table WHERE Name='" + brandName+ "'",null);
```

instead of this what you have tried

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Brand_Table WHERE Name="+brandName, null);
```

branName is a String needs to be in single quote.